MARIADB How to transpose rows to columns without prepared statements
I am trying, in MariaDB, to transpose a unknown number of rows from a query to columns in order to get a single row.

I search about it but mostly examples were related to a knowing number of rows using pivot tables.
what I am trying to obtain is this:

I add this code in request of –ysth:
CREATE TABLE sampleDate(
dateExample varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO sampleDate VALUES('22-01-2024(10:00)');
INSERT INTO sampleDate VALUES('23-02-2024(12:00)');
INSERT INTO sampleDate VALUES('23-04-2024(09:00)');
INSERT INTO sampleDate VALUES('23-10-2024(16:00)');

-- Wanted result
SELECT '22-01-2024(10:00)','23-02-2024(12:00)','23-04-2024(09:00)','23- 
10-2024(16:00)';


I don't think you can. MariaDB has no built-in pivot operator.

FYI, in relational databases, this operation is called pivoting.

You must define columns in the select-list explicitly. You can't do this unless you know the distinct values to use for your pivoted columns. You can't write a query in MariaDB that adds more columns depending on the data values it reads in the same query.

Bill Karwin, Are you suggesting to do it outside of MariaDB?

See https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot

You can handle this display detail better in application code.

technically you can do this using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.  but "without prepared statements" doesn't seem to be your actual problem; can you expand on "related to a knowing number of rows"?  I don't think you've let us know clearly enough what your actual problem is.  can you show some actual sample data (create table and insert statements) and your desired results?  you can absolutely do pivots based on the data without having to know the number or values of the data being pivoted.

I added some code  as you asked –ysth

You would do this like this:
set @sql:=(
  select concat(
    'select ',
    group_concat(quote(dateExample) order by str_to_date(dateExample,'%d-%m-%Y(%H:%i)'))
  ) from sampleDate);
execute immediate @sql

(either as two separate requests from your client or enabling multi statements for your connection)
fiddle
